# FatalThrowableError Class 'App\UserVotes' not found in Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I'm new to Laravel and Working in a project. I faced some error in laravel. Can anyone check it out and tell me what is the problem?

I working in local environment and using **Laragon** as a local server.

[image]

Comment: could you please insert your code?

Comment: Which part should I upload here?

Comment: that part you got this error

Comment: I don't understand which part should I post here, I post here the error what the browser shows me. Do I post controller or config or others?

Comment: yes put controller code here

Answer (score 0):

thats mean , you dont have this class UserVotes in your app folder. , if it is exist , check the namespace of this class .